# Multiple one to many relationships using the same 2 tables in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, relationship

I have a database with 2 tables; Users and Revisions. Revisions has multiple one-to-many relationships to the users table, for example created_by, verified_by, published_by (each field being a foreign key user id).

How would I go about defining this relationship in my Rails models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Revision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, :foreign_key => "created_by", :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :verifier, :foreign_key => "verified_by", :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :publisher, :foreign_key => "published_by", :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :creations, :foreign_key => "created_by", :class_name => "Revision"
  has_many :verifications, :foreign_key => "verified_by",
    :class_name => "Revision"
  has_many :publications, :foreign_key => "published_by",
    :class_name => "Revision"
end
```

Using these models:

```
User.first.creations    #=> [#<Revision>, #<Revision>, ...]
Revision.first.creator  #=>  #<User>
# ...etc., for verifier/verifications and publisher/publications.
```

You should probably change the association names to whatever makes most sense in your app.

Comment: I'm trying this solution in my own issue and I can't seem to get it to work. Would you care to give me a hand here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554590/two-models-with-multiple-foreign-keys